# React native hot reloading stopped working after updating from v0.68 to v0.72

Tags: reactjs, react-native, hot-reload, metro-bundler, fast-refresh

I tried to update react native and all other dependencies versions. Once I created the build hot reloading does not work correctly. It does work when I change some line of code  and hit save in VS code it console log value displayed in the metro but if I do not change anything n hit save it does not console.log the value in the screen which I'm expecting to be logged in the console.
Here's metro.config.js:

```
const { getDefaultConfig, mergeConfig } = require("@react-native/metro-config")

module.exports = function (baseConfig) {
  const defaultConfig = mergeConfig(baseConfig, getDefaultConfig(__dirname))
  const {
    resolver: { assetExts, sourceExts },
  } = defaultConfig

  return mergeConfig(defaultConfig, {
    resolver: {
      assetExts: assetExts.filter((ext) => ext !== "svg"),
      sourceExts: [...sourceExts, "svg", "cjs", "mjs", "cjs"],
      resolverMainFields: ["sbmodern", "react-native", "browser", "main"],
    },
    transformer: {
      babelTransformerPath: require.resolve("react-native-svg-transformer"),
    },
  })
}
```

babel.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"],
  env: {
    production: {},
  },
  plugins: [
    [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators",
      {
        legacy: true,
      },
    ],
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-catch-binding"],
    [
      "babel-plugin-root-import",
      {
        paths: [
          {
            rootPathSuffix: "./app/",
            rootPathPrefix: "~/",
          },
          {
            rootPathSuffix: "./storybook/",
            rootPathPrefix: "~/storybook/",
          },
          {
            rootPathSuffix: "./test/",
            rootPathPrefix: "~/test/",
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
    "react-native-reanimated/plugin",
  ],
}
```